# injecting service into tabs ionic 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, angular, ionic2

I'm following this tutorial [advanced google maps component in ionic 2](http://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-advanced-google-maps-component-in-ionic-2/).

I made it step by step and works perfectly but in single pages only.
On my project I'm planning to use tabs or sidemenu design.

I've already asked on the blog of this tutorial but still no responses.

Thanks in advance any help or advice will be apreciated.

I tried the following with no error in the console.

map.js:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ConnectivityService} from '../../providers/connectivity-service/connectivity-service';
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/map/map.html',
  providers: [ConnectivityService],
})
export class MapPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController],[ConnectivityService]];
  }
  constructor(nav, connectivityService) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.connectivity = connectivityService;
    this.map = null;
    this.mapInitialised = false;
    this.apiKey = null;
    this.loadGoogleMaps();
  }
  loadGoogleMaps(){
    var me = this;
    this.addConnectivityListeners();
    if(typeof google == "undefined" || typeof google.maps == "undefined"){
        console.log("Google maps JavaScript needs to be loaded.");
        this.disableMap();
        if(this.connectivity.isOnline()){
            console.log("online, loading map");
            window.mapInit = function(){
                me.initMap();
                me.enableMap();
            }
            let script = document.createElement("script");
            script.id = "googleMaps";
            if(this.apiKey){
                script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=' + apiKey + '&callback=mapInit';
            } else {
                script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?callback=mapInit';               
            }
            document.body.appendChild(script);  
        }   
    }
    else {
        if(this.connectivity.isOnline()){
            console.log("showing map");
            this.initMap();
            this.enableMap();
        }
        else {
            console.log("disabling map");
            this.disableMap();
        }
    }
  }
  initMap(){
    this.mapInitialised = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position) => {
        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        let mapOptions = {
          center: latLng,
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
  disableMap(){
    console.log("disable map");
  }
  enableMap(){
    console.log("enable map");
  }
  addConnectivityListeners(){
    var me = this;
    var onOnline = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(typeof google == "undefined" || typeof google.maps == "undefined"){
                me.loadGoogleMaps();
            } else {
                if(!me.mapInitialised){
                    me.initMap();
                }
                me.enableMap();
            }
        }, 2000);
    };
    var onOffline = function(){
        me.disableMap();
    };
    document.addEventListener('online', onOnline, false);
    document.addEventListener('offline', onOffline, false);
  }
}`
```

connectivity-service.js:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class ConnectivityService {
  static get parameters(){
    return [[Platform]]
  }  

  constructor(platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.onDevice = this.platform.is('ios') || this.platform.is('android');
  }

  isOnline() {
    if(this.onDevice && navigator.connection){
      let networkState = navigator.connection.type;
      return networkState !== Connection.NONE;
    } else {
      return navigator.onLine;      
    }
  }

  isOffline(){
    if(this.onDevice && navigator.connection){
      let networkState = navigator.connection.type;
      return networkState === Connection.NONE;
    } else {
      return !navigator.onLine;     
    }
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';


@App({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
export class MyApp {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[Platform]];
  }

  constructor(platform) {
    this.rootPage = TabsPage;

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

tabs.html:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="mapPage" tabIcon="map"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="listPage" tabIcon="list-box"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs.js

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
import {MapPage} from '../map/map';
import {ListadoPage} from '../listado/listado';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/tabs/tabs.html',
})
export class TabsPage {
  constructor() {
    this.mapPage = MapPage;
    this.listPage = ListadoPage;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a tabs.html?

Comment: What is the actual problem with injecting you run into?

Comment: Hi @wilburrr90 yes I have it and so tabs.js do you want me to post it?

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer the problem I think it's if the injection of the service it's well done. In a single page project it works as i mentioned I took this implementation from: www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-advanced-google-maps-component-in-ionic-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct architecture, It will also work with menu or tabs or many different pages; sidemenu or tabs is just a way to display pages.

If you worry about accessing the service from the menu or tabs templates themselves, remember that they are just the associated templates of the `@App` class. So to access the service from them, you need to add the service to the `constructor` of the `@App` just like you did for the `@Page` (this you are not doing right now).

Comment: Hi @Manu Valdés I tried what you said and still the same results it doesn't work at all. `constructor(platform,connectivityService){`                                   
    `this.rootPage = TabsPage;`
    `this.connectivity = connectivityService;`
    `platform.ready().then(() => {`
    `});`
  `}`

Comment: I think you need to describe what doesn't work. Seems like you don't really need to access the service from the sidemenu or tabs, so you can remove ConnectivityService from the @App providers and constructor. Just leave it on MapPage. Next thing, you do realize that your '@App' will load TabsPage, not MapPage? just to make sure, show us your TabsPage template, it should have an ion-tab pointing to MapPage, like this:  <ion-tab [root]="MapPage"></ion-tab>

Comment: Hi @Manu Valdés I tried what you said and still the same results it doesn't work at all the map page. I posted the tabs template as you asked and remove the service from app.js. And the error it's still "Google maps JavaScript needs to be loaded" this error is from map.js.

Comment: That is not an error message, it lets us know it's going to load the maps js. Do you get other messages? Can you post to console and server log? (You can activate them feom inside ionic serve with the c and s commands)

Comment: I know it's not an error message indeed. But it's still failing this same code doesn't fails when i'm use it in a single page. Here's the console log: `Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
1     221201   log      Google maps JavaScript needs to be loaded.
2     221209   log      disable map
3     221217   log      online, loading map
4     221485   log      enable map
5     227437   warn     Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys`

Comment: it looks like the service is injected and working properly, I'd say you need to debug the DOM to check where the map is attaching itself to the document, and why is it different in a single page vs. a tabbed interface.

Comment: thanks for your help I knew everithing was right but I forgot to worry about frontend it was the ```app.core.scss``` it was empty. Now it's working sorry for wasting your time. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot `providers:[...]` in your map component

Comment: Hi @qchap you refer to this: [ConnectivityService] that's how it's named the providers. Where do you sugest it's missing?

Comment: Yes inside of your @page

Comment: I've already attempt doing that way including providers on map.js and it doesn't change. I sincerly tried a lot of combinations.                                                                       @Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/map/map.html',
  providers: [ConnectivityService],
})